# Кодировка для Windows Server R2

Tags: java, кодировка, windows-server-2012

Использую `Windows Server 2012 R2`, возникла проблема с кодировкой. При попытке изпользовать кирилличиские символы в простейшем `System.out.println("абвг")` получаю иероглифы. Что интересно в `PowerShell` при попытке просто печатать в него кирилицу - это получается, при попытке запуска консольного приложения -  иероглифы. С `cmd` иероглифы получаются в обоих случаях. JVM v1.8.0_161.

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>oasis</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>2.0</version>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${file.encoding}</encoding>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.app.Application</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <spring-version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <logback.version>1.0.10</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.3</slf4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ....
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Как компилировали программу?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev через maven c манифестом, запускаю просто java -jar app.jar

Comment: Параметр `sourceEncoding` в pom.xml указан?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev вот так выглядит мой pom.xml именно sourceEncoding такого нет, есть только просто <encoding>.

Comment: Вместо `${file.encoding}` укажите UTF-8 и убедитесь, что исходный код именно в этой кодировке.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev а как убедиться просто посмотреть соберется ли? Соберается.

Comment: Открыть исходник каким-нибудь редактором, который позволяет посмотреть\изменить текущую кодировку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В cmd выполняем `chcp` видим

`C:\>chcp
Текущая кодовая страница: 866`

Варианты:

- Компилироваться для этой кодировки - тогда программа будет хорошо разговаривать в cmd и плохо во всех остальных местах;
- Писать все в utf-8 а запускаться батником, в котором сначала выполняем `chcp 65001` (определение кодовой страницы) а потом `java -jar ...`

Для  ps набор команд немного более замороченный, но смысл тот же.